# NextJS not running on MacOS even after installing modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, node-modules

So I've just created a NextJS project using `create-next-app` which went smoothly as expected. Then ran `npm i` just to be sure and saw all modules installed into `node_modules`

When I try to run `npm run dev` to start my nextjs app. it just says

```
sh: next: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! test@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/john.v.n.pakson/.npm/_logs/2022-10-06T08_01_29_725Z-debug.log
```

It seems like npm is not detecting the `node_modules` i have installed.

Not sure if this is a mac or a zsh issue.

I'm using node version `12.22.12`

Upgraded to `16.17.1` and still see the same error

```
> test@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

/var/folders/6y/xtlzp4z16dj0stxnqx8znj8w0000gn/T/dev-01c08137.sh: line 1: next: command not found
```

Comment: Did you install your "global" `next`? `npm install -g global` or Yarn equivalent if using that.

Comment: Is it required to install `next` globally?

Comment: no, it is not required globally, try removing node_modules and doing a npm install to see if that fixes it

Comment: hmmm reason actually is my file path. my project was in a folder with `Project/Test` as a name. I assume npm or zsh got confused cause once I moved it to another folder I could run `npm run dev` already

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured it out. It was caused by my file path on macos. My project was on a folder called `Project/Test` which might have confused zsh or mac. This in turn caused npm to not be able to find the correct scripts on my `node_modules`

When I moved my project to another folder I was already able to run `npm run dev` properly.

Cheers!

Comment: Putting a `/` in a directory name is one way to really confuse things. Good catch!